# Plotting multiple JSON subobjects in Chart.js Line chart ( with Time as x-axis)

Tags: json, django, chart.js

I'm trying to plot data from multiple channels in Django.
My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "Channel1":[
    {
      "Value":123,
      "Timestamp": someUnixTime
    },
    {
      "Value":456,
      "Timestamp": someUnixTime
    },
    {
      "Value":789,
      "Timestamp": someUnixTime
    }
  ],
  "Channel2":[
    {
      "Value":312,
      "Timestamp": someUnixTime
    },
    {
      "Value":654,
      "Timestamp": someUnixTime
    },
    {
      "Value":987,
      "Timestamp": someUnixTime
    }
  ]
}
```

My chart.html looks like this

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<script>
{% block jquery %}
var endpoint = 'api/chart/data/' //{%url "api-data" %}
var json_data = []
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: endpoint,
  success: function(data){
    json_data = data
    setChart()
    console.log(data)
  },
  error: function(error_data){
    console.log("error")
    console.log(error_data)
  }
})

function setChart(){
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {}
  });
}


{% endblock %}
</script>

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" url-endpoint='{% url "api-data" %}'>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

With my view.py looking like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'charts.html', {})


class ChartData(APIView):

    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        json_data = open("data_json.json","r")
        #labels = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange']
        #default_items = [123,156,140,200,132,200]
        data = json.load(json_data)
        return Response(data)
```

The Problem is I don't know how I can cycle through each JSON object to use them as data in the chart.html.

P.S. My actual dataset has somewhat around 73 channels and +100k entries.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I found a way to prepare the data in a way I need.
By cycling through the JSON object and building an array based on that.
async function prepData(){

```
  var chartLabel = [];
  var data_points = [];
  var dataset = [];
  var entry = [];
  var data_point = [];
  for (var channel in json_data){
    data_points = [];
    dataset = [];
    entry = [];
    chartLabel = [];

    chartLabels.push(channel);
    for(entry in json_data[channel]){
      data_point = {
        y:json_data[channel][entry].Value,
        t:json_data[channel][entry].Timestamp
      };
      data_points.push(data_point);
    };

    dataset = {
      label: channel,
      data: data_points
    };
    //console.log(dataset);
    chartData.push(dataset)
  };
  console.log(chartData);
  console.log(chartLabels)
}
```